# Get total from excel records

Tags: excel, csv

I have a problem with csv for example, i have multiple rows with a date and a price with more of the same date and time for example

```
01-01-2015 10:00, 10.00
01-01-2015 11:00, 12.00
01-01-2015 12:00, 9.00
02-01-2015 11:00, 4.00
02-01-2015 13:00, 6.50
```

There are thousands of rows like this and what i try to accomplish with excel is to get the total from all the days so with the example data i would want the following result:

```
01-01-2015, 31.00
02-01-2015, 10.50
```

Does anyone know an ease way to accomplish this (keep in mind that the file involves thousands records)

I also hope that i used the right forum for this problem, i couldn't find a specific forum for excel or office on this website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new column. assuming that your first date on is in cell A2 (If it is on A1 then insert header first. it will be important to the pivot table) and your first price is on cell B2 the on C2 enter `=rounddown(A2,0)` this will extract the date with no hour.
Then, insert a pivot table. select all your data and on the insert ribbon press insert pivot table. Drag all the fixed date for the row and the price drag for the value. If the values are on count,  change the values from count to sum by  clicking the definition field.

Comment: `=ROUND(A2,0)` will round `02-01-2015 13:00` to `03-01-2015`. I would prefer `=INT(a2)` instead.

Comment: Yes Alex, you are right. I am changing to round down.